# Entity Framework - stored procedure return value

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to get the return value of a stored procedure. Here is an example of such a stored procedure:

```
select
    Name,
    IsEnabled
from
    dbo.something
where
    ID = @ID

if @@rowcount = 0
    return 1    

return
```

This is a simple select. If 0 rows are found, my result set will be null, but I will still have a return value.

This is a bad example, as this is a select, so sure I could find if 0 rows were returned. However, on an Insert, delete, or other calls, we need this return value to know if there was a problem. I have been unable to find a way to get this return value. I can get output values, I can get result sets, but no return value.

I can get the return value if I call SQL manually, or even if I run a `SqlCommand` using the Entity Framework, but this is not what I want to do.

Has anyone ever been able to get the return value from a stored procedure using Entity Framework?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Entity Framework is an ORM and is not intended to completely replace all calls to the database made from your application.

Comment: _I can get the return value if I call SQL manually, or even if I run a SQLCommand using the entity framework_ - that's your answer.

Comment: @Lamak - Whoops my mistake, I saw it under 50% and assumed the worst.

Comment: I have been able to get the return value (and also output and input parameters) with Entity Framework 5 (but I think it works from version 4.x) using the code first approach. From your post I don't see what version of EF you are using and how you're doing your mapping; if you consider to use code-first approach here you can find my post with the solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/entity-framework-code-first-get-return-value-from-stored-procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/entity-framework-code-first-get-return-value-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Entity Framework doesn't have rich stored procedure support because its an ORM, not a SQL replacement.

As you have already discovered, if you need to use less common (more advanced?) features of stored procedures, you'll have to use good old fashioned ADO.NET.

Comment: To add to this: @@rowcount will return a scalar value, or for that matter, any select @value will return a scalar value. If you already have a result set, this will add a new result set. Currently, 4.0 does not support multiple result sets, but Framework 4.5 with EF will support multiple result sets.

Answer (score 6):

I guess support of stored procedure return values depends on version of Entity framework. Although directly returning value didn't work for me I managed to get value using OUTPUT stored procedure parameter. Example:

```
USE [YOUR_DB_NAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestReturnValue]
    @InputValue int = 0,
    @Result int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @Result  = @InputValue
    RETURN(@InputValue);
END
```

This is test code:

```
void TestReturnValue()
{
    using (var db = new YourDBContext())
    {
        var result = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("Result", 0);
        Console.WriteLine("SP returned {0}", db.TestReturnValue(123, result));
        Console.WriteLine("Output param {0}", result.Value);
    }
}
```

And this is output:

```
SP returned -1
Output param 123
```

As you see directly returned value output some rubbish but OUTPUT parameters works!

[This article provides general info on two ways of returning values from SP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You must use the "Context.Database.SqlQuery",and specify the output type of the stored procedure

```
        var spReturnVaue = Context.Database.SqlQuery<Type>("[schema].YourSp").FirstOrDefault();

        int firstId = Context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("[dbo].GetFirstId").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Hadi Salehy's answer, I wrote this code and works for me.

**My SP**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [schema].[ProcedureName]
@param1 int,
@param2 varchar(20),
@param3 varchar(50)
AS
UPDATE Table1
SET Field2 = @param2, Fiedl3 = @param3
WHERE (Field1 = @param1)
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

**My C# code.**

`int quantity = await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("[schema].[ProcedureName] {0}, {1}, {2}", myModel.Param1, myModel.Param2, myModel.Param3);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var parms = new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Data", Value = date},
    new SqlParameter { 
        ParameterName = "@returnValue", 
        Value = -123, 
        SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 
        Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
    }
};

var sql = "EXEC @returnValue = db.dbo.spDoSomething @Data;";
var retProc = await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql, parms.ToArray());

var returnValue = (int)parms[1].Value;
```

Answer (score -2):

In order to get the interested result in EF, you should return a same structure (not 1 and Name, IsEnabled)
In this query you should return '',0 for example instead of 1 in the if condition:

```
select
    Name,
    IsEnabled
from
    dbo.something
where
    ID = @ID

if @@rowcount = 0
    return '',0
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the question?