# SQL return code with Razor

Tags: sql, razor

I am looking for a way to get the SQL return code when issuing any database commmand using razor.  I haven't found any examples.  Is the SQL return code returned with the result set?
For example,

```
var products = db.Query("SELECT * FROM products");
```

will give you the the result set but if there is a database error, the only way that I can think of to display the error is through a try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

[Get return value from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/entity-framework-code-first-get-return-value-from-stored-procedure)

```
var returnCode = new SqlParameter();
returnCode.ParameterName = "@ReturnCode";
returnCode.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
returnCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

// assign the return code to the new output parameter and pass it to the sp
var data = _context.Database.SqlQuery<Item>("exec @ReturnCode = spItemData @Code, @StatusLog OUT", returnCode, code, outParam);
```