# EF 6.1 T-SQL RETURN WRONG RESULT (SQL SERVER 2012)

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have the following Store Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SP_DELETE_ASSEMBLY] 
@FullAssemblyName nvarchar(300)
AS 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (@FullAssemblyName IS NULL) OR (LEN(@FullAssemblyName) = 0)
    RETURN -10

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [TB_DYNAMICASSEMBLIES] WHERE [FullAssemblyName] = @FullAssemblyName)
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM [TB_DYNAMICASSEMBLIES]
    WHERE [FullAssemblyName] = @FullAssemblyName
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    RETURN -10
END

RETURN 10

GO
```

I'm using EF 6.1 by using this call to the store procedure:

```
return entities.SP_DELETE_ASSEMBLY(assemblyName);
```

However I call the store procedure I always get -1 as return.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer

[Get return value from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure)

You can achieve this using an output parameter