# Using Entity Framework, should I use RETURN or SELECT in my stored procedures?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am currently trying to use stored procedures with Entity Framework and I am encountering a problem with return type.

The return type of my stored procedure is BIT.

Here is the code (simplified) of my stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_makeStuff]
    @id int
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @status BIT

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @id
            SET @status = 1

            COMMIT
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            SET @status = 0
            ROLLBACK
        END CATCH 

        RETURN @status

    END 
END
```

I added sp_makeStuff in my .edmx file with return type bool?.

Then, I try to execute it with the code below

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    ObjectResult<bool?> result = ctx.sp_makeStuff(id);
    if (result.FirstOrDefault().Value) 
    {
        // Stuff
    }   
}
```

However, it raises an exception of type System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException, whose message is "The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have enough columns for the query requested."

After some investigation, I found that it works if I replace

```
RETURN @status
```

by

```
SELECT @status
```

In the past, I always used the T-SQL "RETURN" keyword to return such a result.

I am wondering if my new implementation is correct.
As I want to use EF in my projects, is there a mean to make it work with "RESULT" or do I have to use "SELECT" definitively ?

Thanks.

**EDIT 24/10/2014**

Based on responses below, I re-wrote my stored procedure. Instead of returning something, it raises an error if something goes wrong.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_makeStuff]
    @id int
AS
    BEGIN

        BEGIN TRY
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Id = @id

            COMMIT
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK
            RAISERROR('Delete failed', 16, -1)
        END CATCH 

    END 
END
```

Then, I told to EF that my stored procedure returns nothing, and I deal with the exception if RAISERROR is called.

```
try
{
    ctx.sp_web_DeleteElement(elementId);
    // ...
}
catch (Exception e) // Message in e.InnerException.Message
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I think the best way with EF is to use an [Output parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb896334%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for your return code. Alternatively [this workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14735479/1048425) may help?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks for this tip @marc_s. Fortunately, our project has only 400 stored procedures with sp_ prefix :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the past, I always used the T-SQL "RETURN" keyword to return such a
>   result.

A stored procedure return code can only be an integer.  Its purpose is to indicate success or failure to the calling application, not to return data.  Return data using an OUTPUT parameter or result set.

The return value convention is that a zero indicates success and non-zero for error/warning.  The non-zero value may also be used to indicate specific the specific cause (e.g. 99 for customer not found during an update attempt) as an alternative to raising an error.  By default, SQL Server will return a negative value if any errors with severity of 10 or higher were raised.