# data reader is incompatible with the specified. A member of the type, does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

So I am using a Stored Procedure to Add a new user to db in a test MVC application using C#.

I keep getting an error, and I believed it was caused by the fact that I was returning the ID of the newly added user to the db, commenting out the code did nothing :(, or rather it gave me the same error but complaining about a different variable.

The funny thing is, it successfully adds a user just fine, except it throws an exception.

I would still like to return the ID to the calling program, and I would still like to this with a parameterized query.

**Code Below:**

```
#region AddUser
public static bool AddUser(Models.User user)
{
    bool result = false;
    Models.UserRegistrationPasswordsEntities1 db = new Models.UserRegistrationPasswordsEntities1();
    var queryResult = db.Users.SqlQuery(@"EXECUTE uspAddUser @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6",
                                        new SqlParameter("1", user.userFirstName),
                                        new SqlParameter("2", user.userLastName),
                                        new SqlParameter("3", user.userName),
                                        new SqlParameter("4", user.userEmail),
                                        new SqlParameter("5", user.userPassword),
                                        new SqlParameter("6", user.userDateOfBirth)).Single();


    // the ternary opertor is pretty awesome
    result = queryResult == null ? false : true;

    return result;
}
#endregion
```

**Model.user below:**

```
public partial class User
{
    public int userID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage ="First name required")]
    public string userFirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Last name required")]
    public string userLastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Username required")]
    public string userName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "email is required")]
    public string userEmail { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth is required")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime userDateOfBirth { get; set;}


    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [MinLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Minimum of 6 characters required")]
    public string userPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required")]
    [Compare("userPassword", ErrorMessage = "Confirm password and password do not match")]
    public string userConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public bool userStatus { get; set; }
    public bool userEmailVerificationStatus { get; set; }

    public System.Guid userActivationCode { get; set; }
}
```

**Error Below:**  
This is the error I receive with the stored procedure code commented out as seen below. If I uncomment it screams about `userFirstName`

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'UserRegistrationPasswordsModel.User'. A member of the type, 'userID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

**Create Table Below:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] (
    [userID]                      INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [userFirstName]               VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [userLastName]                VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [userName]                    VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [userEmail]                   VARCHAR (50)     NOT NULL,
    [userPassword]                VARCHAR (255)    NOT NULL,
    [userStatus]                  BIT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [userEmailVerificationStatus] BIT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [userActivationCode]          UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT (newid()) NOT NULL,
    [userDateOfBirth]             DATETIME         NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([userID] ASC)
);
```

**Stored Procedure below:** 

 Note that the SELECT at the bottom is commented out cause I thought that maybe returning the ID to the calling program was the problem. In my final solution I would like to still return the Id to the calling program in this way if at all possible.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddUser
 @userFirstName                 VARCHAR(50)
,@userLastName                  VARCHAR(50)
,@userName                      VARCHAR(50)
,@userEmail                     VARCHAR(50)
,@userPassword                  VARCHAR(100)
,@userDateOfBirth               DATETIME

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON      -- Report Only Errors
SET XACT_ABORT ON   -- Rollback transaction on error

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @userID  INTEGER

-- CREATE new record
INSERT INTO Users(userFirstName, userLastName, userName, userEmail, userPassword, userStatus, userEmailVerificationStatus, userDateOfBirth)
VALUES(@userFirstName, @userLastName, @userName, @userEmail, @userPassword, 0 ,0, @userDateOfBirth)  -- 1 = Active

---- return ID to calling program
--SELECT UserID FROM Users WHERE userFirstName = @userFirstName AND
--                             userLastName = @userLastName   AND
--                             userName = @userName           AND
--                             userEmail = @userEmail

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**Resources I accessed searching for solution below:**  
[Exception : Execute Insert Stored Procedure using Entity framework ExecuteStoreQuery function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27401529/exception-execute-insert-stored-procedure-using-entity-framework-executestoreq?rq=1)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/diego/2012/01/09/stored-procedures-with-output-parameters-using-sqlquery-in-the-dbcontext-api/

[Get return value from stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure/14735479#14735479)

[Using Entity Framework, should I use RETURN or SELECT in my stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26545880/using-entity-framework-should-i-use-return-or-select-in-my-stored-procedures)

Any and all help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: have you tried putting attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` on `userID` in C# User Model ?

Comment: Try returning full entity instead of just single `userID` (note that the column name passed to `db.Users` must have exactly same name with passed columns from SP). Also put `[Key]` and `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` on top of `userId` property.

Comment: thank you for the tip with  [key]  and [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]. Is there anyway to just return the ID? I also updated the description of the error above to include more information if needed.

Comment: Side-note: while you find the conditional operator pretty awesome, you can write even simpler code here: `return queryResult != null;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you need to return [full part of the entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx) when using `SELECT` statement with `SqlQuery` method (instead of single property). Change the `SELECT` statement inside stored procedure to this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Users 
WHERE userFirstName = @userFirstName AND userLastName = @userLastName 
AND userName = @userName AND userEmail = @userEmail
```

Then, execute it into `queryResult`:

```
var queryResult = db.Users.SqlQuery(@"EXECUTE uspAddUser @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6",
                                        new SqlParameter("1", user.userFirstName),
                                        new SqlParameter("2", user.userLastName),
                                        new SqlParameter("3", user.userName),
                                        new SqlParameter("4", user.userEmail),
                                        new SqlParameter("5", user.userPassword),
                                        new SqlParameter("6", user.userDateOfBirth)).Single();
```

If you wish to obtain `userID` from `AddUser` method, you can call it from the query result above (and change return type to `int` instead of `bool`):

```
int userId = queryResult.userID;

return userId;
```

**Side note:**

Since `userID` declared as primary key identity column, put `KeyAttribute` and `DatabaseGeneratedAttribute` to set corresponding property as primary key in EF model class:

```
public partial class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int userID { get; set; }

    // other properties

}
```

Similar issue:

[does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24732320/does-not-have-a-corresponding-column-in-the-data-reader-with-the-same-name)

Comment: This is my answer. Thank you very much, I guess I am gonna have to get used to that this is just how this works in the Entity Framework.