# Creating and using a stored proc to check TVP values

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to create a function that will take a TVP and check if another table has matching entries for every value in the TVP and return a simple bit to indicate if they all match or not. So I have something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[fCheckAccess]
@userId int,
@items dbo.TypeCodeInteger READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @count int
    DECLARE @rCount int
    DECLARE @bit BIT

    SET @count = (SELECT count(vr.code)
    from @items r left join dbo.vAccess vr
    on r.Code = vr.code and r.Type = vr.type 
    where vr.uid = @userId)

    SET @rCount = (SELECT count(*) from @items)

    set @bit = IIF(@count = @rCount, 1, 0)

    return @bit
END
```

So the idea is to join the TVP with the `vAccess` table and count the number of matching rows. Then compare this with the number of rows in the TVP and return 1 or 0. I'm thinking there is probably a more concise way to do this.

Now my problem is trying to actually access this using entity framework. I tried something like this:

```
using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
{
    var r = new DataTable();
    r.Columns.Add("Type",typeof(byte));
    r.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(int));
    r.Rows.Add(2, 5);
    r.Rows.Add(1, 760);
    r.Rows.Add(4, 39);
    r.Rows.Add(2, 1746);
    r.Rows.Add(2, 1);
    r.Rows.Add(2, 2);

    var b = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<int>("EXEC dbo.fCheckAccess @userId, @items",
        new SqlParameter("@userId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 1893 },
        new SqlParameter("@regions", r) { TypeName = "TypeCodeInteger" });

    Console.WriteLine(b.First());
}
```

But this doesn't work. On the `Console.WriteLine` line, I get an `EntityCommandExecutionException` with the message:

```
The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for 
EDM primitive or enumeration types.
```

So what's the best way to make this work?

Comment: Is the error because you are `return`ing rather than `select`ing? I don't use EF but looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure) it looks like you might need to use an output parameter if you want to keep the return.

Comment: @petelids: Thanks. That actually did help quite a bit and I've managed to pull pieces from that and get it working. Not sure it's the right or best way to do it, but at least I have something working for right now.