# How to get stored procedure return value using linq with C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

have a stored Procedure that do some operation and return 1 or 0 as below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.UserCheckUsername11
(
    @Username nvarchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF Exists(SELECT UserID FROM User WHERE username =@Username) 
    return 1
ELSE
    return 0
END
```

Using linq I tried to get return value. But i am getting the output as -1 always.

Below is my Linq code :

```
 using (PlanGenEntities3 entity2 = new PlanGenEntities3())
 {                
    var result = entity2.Entity_test_GetHoliday();
    string output = result.ToString();
 }
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: have a look here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: It seems like you're calling the wrong stored procedure. In your SQL it's called "UserCheckUsername1" but in code you're calling "Entity_test_GetHoliday"; unless you manually mapped it to a different name...

Comment: Your code and sql are 2 different things...

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Entity_test_GetHoliday is my EntityContainer Stored procedure name. Just for sample i tried to put the code. Can you please help me to solve how to get stored procedure retun values.

Comment: Any one plese help me to pass some sample codes to solve this issues

Comment: Hi @Dhamo you can check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399357(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @ArunGairola, Thanks for posting. I would like to do and get the retrun values from stored procedure without using any custome functions. How can i do it & using Entity Framework.

Comment: Maybe, you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14735479/4715873)

Comment: Try to use Output parameter of Store procedure then Linq will understand what you want to return.

Comment: Solution found : using (PlanGenEntities3 entity2 = new PlanGenEntities3())
            {
                // name is an output parameter.
                ObjectParameter name = new ObjectParameter("Ret", typeof(int));
                entity2.Entity_test_GetHoliday(name);
                //Get stored procedure return values:
                string getOutput = name.Value.ToString();
            }

Comment: Now i can get the return values from stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare your scalar variable as a output parameter for SQL query, then in the code you could retrieve its value this way:
```

```
using (PlanGenEntities3 myContext = new PlanGenEntities3())            
{                
   var outputParameter = new System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter("OutputParameterName", typeof(int));                
   myContext.Entity_test_GetHoliday(outputParameter );                
   Console.WriteLine(outputParameter.Value);            
}
```

```

I suppose there is way to access the default scalar output of your SP in the similar manor.

Answer (score 0):

If he had it as an output parameter it would automatically show as a reference parameter of the proper corresponding data type in the LINQ call.

He wouldn't really need to create a parameter object to contain that.