# Get return value from stored procedure using ExecuteSqlCommand (using Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I have code that looks like this:

```
int retval = databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command, sqlParameters.ToArray());
```

Where databaseContext is of type System.Data.Entity.DbContext

I want to use the return value to know whether or not the stored procedure ran successfuly.  Based on [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(System.String,System.Object[])) `ExecuteSqlCommand` should return the result of the stored procedure.

However, The command always returns -1 to retval, no matter what I set the stored procedure to do.  I've tried returning various integers and even calling RAISERROR in the stored procedure, but the return value is consistently -1.

Here are two stored procs I tried but they both returned -1 and did not give any indication of whether it ran successfully or not:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
AS
BEGIN
      RAISERROR ('You fail', -- Message text.
                       0, -- Severity - operation failed.
                       500-- State.
                       );
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myproc]
AS
BEGIN
      RETURN 1
END
GO
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get return value from stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure)

Comment: @DavidG, no this is a different issue. That question requires the query to be in a particular format, while the ExecuteSqlCommand documentation doesn't seem to require any such thing

Comment: If you want the return value, you have to use that method. `ExecuteSqlCommand` won't do it for you, unless possibly something `SELECT`s the value into a result set.

Comment: @DavidG, ah, I see. I had seen that answer you linked but hadn't understood the difference. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Not really worth posting an answer for that comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on DavidG's comment:

ExecuteSqlCommand only returns values if it's the result of a select statement.

If you want the return value of a stored procedure (like shown in the question), then you have to use the `EXEC @ReturnValue = [StoredProc] @param1 ...` method as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure).