# Why does EF Core always return -1 with this stored procedure?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, localdb

I am trying to use EF Core (latest release) against a Local 2016 DB and I am getting `-1` back every time. I don't know what I have done wrong?

I know that it is reaching the database. I checked that.

```
int returnCode = _dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CheckReceivedNotificationDuplicate @p0, @p1, @p2", 
parameters: new[] { sendMessage.MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME, sendMessage.MESSAGE_SUBJECT, sendMessage.MESSAGE_TEXT_SUMMARY });
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckReceivedNotificationDuplicate]
@MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME nvarchar(100),
@MESSAGE_SUBJECT nvarchar(255),
@MESSAGE_TEXT_SUMMARY nvarchar(4000)
AS  DECLARE @NMID Int
BEGIN   
IF  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Notification WHERE MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME = @MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME
                and MESSAGE_SUBJECT = @MESSAGE_SUBJECT AND ReceiveTimeEST > dateadd(minute,-5, dbo.GetGMTtoEST(getutcdate())))
BEGIN 
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Notification WHERE MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME = @MESSAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME
                and MESSAGE_SUBJECT = @MESSAGE_SUBJECT AND MESSAGE_TEXT_SUMMARY = @MESSAGE_TEXT_SUMMARY
                AND ReceiveTimeEST > dateadd(minute,-5, dbo.GetGMTtoEST(getutcdate())))
        RETURN -99
    ELSE
        RETURN 0
END
ELSE
    RETURN 0
END
```

Comment: Do any of these suggestions help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735477/get-return-value-from-stored-procedure

Comment: Your SQL doesn't perform any DDL operations, you should recreate it as a UDF or VIEW.

Comment: ^ how does this help? This is a question and answer site, not a place to tell people they did things wrong. Yeah there's alot of should have done it this way you can say about any code. But, if you don't have something nice or helpful to say, don't say anything at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ExecuteSqlCommand` calls [`IRelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/dev/src/EFCore.Relational/Storage/IRelationalCommand.cs#L39) internally. It returns the number of rows affected.

To return an arbitrary value from stored procedure, add output parameter to its declaration and to `ExecuteSqlCommand` call:

```
var outParameter = new SqlParameter("@outParameter", DbType.Int32)
{
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
};

context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec GetFoo @outParameter OUT", outParameter);
```

Comment: Excellent, what a good answer! Thanks so much for your help! I left on Friday really worried about this, but I said why not post it to Stack and see if I get lucky. Monday will be a good day!

Comment: This is a fine answer if one has the ability to change the stored procedure.