# Calling Stored Procedure In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following part in the end of a SQL Server stored procedure:

```
if(@someValue < 0)
  begin
    SELECT @resultIsSuccess = 0
    Return @resultIsSuccess
  end
else
  begin
    SELECT @resultIsSuccess = 1
    Return @resultIsSuccess
  end
```

where `@resultIsSuccess` is of type `bit`.

So, basically I am returning a bool to indicate if the procedure yielded the intended result.

On the EF side, I configured the Function Import's return type as boolean.

When I call:

```
bool isSuccess = context.MyFunctionImport(arg1, arg2).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

I get the following exception:

> The data reader returned by the store data provider does not have
>   enough columns for the query requested.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Why not try `SELECT 0` or `SELECT 1` instead of adding an extra line and declaring a variable? It could be because you aren't actually "reading" anything but you are outputting to an return variable.

Comment: You should never use the return value of a stored procedure to return data.  Use an output parameter or a resultset.

Answer (score 2):

If you are returning a value, you need a return parameter. Therefore you aren't using a `datareader` to get your value. You aren't `select`ing anything therefore you would need to have access to that return parameter.

Instead `select` your values to populate the `datareader` since you are probably getting an error when you try to read values from a noninstantiated `datareader` through EF.

```
if(@someValue < 0)
    SELECT 0
else
    SELECT 1
```

I'm unsure if return values are supported, [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339750/entity-framework-stored-procedure-return-value), so you may be trying to do the impossible unless fixed in a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that you are NOT returning a bit datatype from your procedure. The return datatype of a stored procedure is int.

You could greatly simplify your code to a single line return statement.

```
return case when @someValue < 0 then 0 else 1 end
```

Then in your code you would need to parse the 0 or 1 to a boolean.

--EDIT--
Since you are looking for the first value you will need to use a select statement in your procedure. Something like this.

```
Select isSuccess  = case when @someValue < 0 then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: I tried this but it calling the function always return 1. Even though I changed the return values to be numbers such as 5 or 6, it returned 1.

Comment: How are you checking your return? RETURN_VALUE. Honestly you should probably be using an OUTPUT parameter.

Comment: I am doing int isSuccess = context.MyFunctionImport(arg1, arg2);

Comment: Ah....then you are getting the values from the first select statement in your procedure...NOT the return value.