# Entity Framework returns the wrong value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have this SQL Server stored procedure:

```
    @UserName VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Result INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT LoginID 
    FROM Personnel
    WHERE LoginID = @UserName AND Administrator = 'Y'

    SET @Result = @@ROWCOUNT

    RETURN @Result
END
```

When I test it I get the results back as expected, I get either 1 row or a 0 row count.

I call the stored procedure from my C# application with this code:

```
private void ValidateUser(string user)
{
    using (ComplaintsEntities db = new ComplaintsEntities())
    {
        var t = db.AAGetAdminStatus(user,0);
    }
}
```

When I test with a good user account I should get a result of `1` and if my user is not admin I should get a result of `0`. When I inspect the return value in the C# code, it always returns `-1`. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please provide the source for AAGetAdminStatus

Comment: Broadly speaking, Entity Framework dislikes the `RETURN x` keyword, and doesn't play well with it. You would do better by either using an `OUTPUT` parameter (`...@Result int OUTPUT`), or by using `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` to output your value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - stored procedure return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339750/entity-framework-stored-procedure-return-value)

Comment: I think this is an EF6 bug.  I have a similar problem but EF returns -1 each time instead of the correct value (which is returned when calling sproc from SSMS).  The data is insert into the database correctly though.  Disappointing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@UserName varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Insert statements for procedure here
  Select count(LoginID) UserCount
  from Personnel
  where LoginID = @UserName And Administrator = 'Y'

END
```

Entity code:

```
private void ValidateUser(string user)
{
    using (ComplaintsEntities db = new ComplaintsEntities())
    {
        var t = db.AAGetAdminStatus(user).First().UserCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: to avoid throwing an exception just use `FirstOrDefault()` method.

Comment: I used First() because stored procedure will return one row and one column contains the count

Answer (score 0):

Mostafa's answer kind of  worked.  I used his SQL code to return the count but had to modify the C# code a little.  Had to change it to.

```
var x = db.AAGetAdminStatus(user).First();
```

Once I did that I had what I needed.

Comment: Thanks for the remider